# Find sum of series whose general term is $(k^2+1)\cdot k!$

Tags: sequences-and-series

> Find the sum to $100$ terms for a series whose general term can be expressed as $A(k)=(k^2+1)\cdot k!$

---

I tried to solve directly, but that requires sum of the factorials, too complex. Help with a generous method.

Comment: Does "." mean "$\times$"?

Comment: Hint: $k^2 + 1 = k(k+1) - (k-1)$ and $(k+1)k! = (k+1)!$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\sum_{k=1}^{100}A(k){=\sum_{k=1}^{100}(k^2+1)k!\\=\sum_{k=1}^{100} (k^2+k-(k-1))k!\\= \sum_{k=1}^{100}k(k+1)!-(k-1)k!\\=100\times 101!}$$